# Navigation Drawer statusbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

I'm having trouble making **Navigation drawer** over **statusbar**.

I'm using new Design support library. In [blogspot](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) thay said:

> NavigationView takes care of the scrim protection of the status bar
>   for you, ensuring that your NavigationView interacts with the status
>   bar appropriately on API21+ devices.

*But it has no documentation so I'm very confused how to use Drawer to achieve desired effect.*

I tried inserting following attributes in my styles-v21:

```
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

after this Navigation drawer is working as needed **but**, 
other activities have transparent statusbar.

Can somebody give me a better solution?

Comment: Post your layout and your styles.

Comment: Thank you for respince gabriele, i found answer and i will answer&close the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution here is to create special theme for activity with navigation like this.

in styles.xml

```
<style name="NavigationDrawerTheme" parent="AppTheme"/>
```

but in styles v21 you will override this as

```
<style name="NavigationDrawerTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

and in `AndroidManifest.xml` you will set

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/NavigationDrawerTheme"
    android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_main" />
```

So you will have correct behavior in all activities. :-)

P.S
If someone needs more explanation, comment.