# Android | Navigation Drawer Fragment on top StatusBar

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-statusbar

I used fragment to act as the listview in navigation drawer (as instructed by android developers guide). It's work fine to me, but now I have to put the status bar **under** the drawer layout - not otherwise with transparent status bar.
I have searched around and only found 1 potential solution provided in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369243/navigation-drawer-statusbar). But it's not working. I would like to comment for more info but I dont have commentator privilege yet, so I start a new question.

Answer (score 1):

In theme of your App in `style.xml`
add   `<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>`

Comment: It's not working for me. Beside my app support min-sdk API 11, this require API 21.

Comment: I put it in v21/style, but it not works. Is it because I use fragment as drawer layout?

Comment: @PhuongDao add theme to your launcher activity in manifest file.

Comment: yeah, I forgot about it.However,result isn't what I wanted, it makes statusbar transparent and you can still see it covers part of the drawer. I think the only way to accomplish my goal is to make my own custom bar.

Comment: @PhuongDao You can try that.